# How to write the below query using subquery?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

I am trying to fetch currency from country table if row exists else return null as written in below code.

```
$country = Country::where("id", 619);
if($country->exists()){
    $currency = $country->first()->currency;
} else {
    $currency = "USD;";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy to write solution would be

```
$currency = Country::where("id", 619)->value('currency') ?? 'USD;';
```

This will not load an instance of Country (doesnt use `first()`) and will return the value of the "currency" attribute or `null` if no result is available.

Comment: Thanks i didn't know it was so simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this shortcut

```
$currency = Country::where("id", 619)->first()->currency ?? 'USD';
```

This will return the currency if country exists and if it doesn't exist it will return USD

Answer (score 0):

You have to first add a relation in your model. You can find this [in the documentation of Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships). After this you have multiple ways to do this, for only a check the best way is the `::has($relation)` function that you can find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Another option you have is to join the table with the function `::with($relation)`. After doing this you can check the columns of the joined table with the `::where($column, $value)` function like you are used to. I think this answers your question how to make a subquery.

**Example of the relation function in the model class.**

```php
function currency() {
  return $this->hasOne(Country:class, 'code', 'country');
}
```

**Example of a subquery**

```php
$hasCurrency = Country::has('currency');
$currency = null;

if ($hasCurrency) {
  $result = Country::with('currency')
    ->where('id', 619)
    ->where('currency.active', 1)
    ->first();

  $currency = $result->currency->code;
}
```

Comment: I think currency here is just an attribute of Country and not another model.